# Generic method to catch and handle exceptions thrown in child classes

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Assuming I have a parent class:

```
class Parent {

    //...

}
```

and a child class with methods:

```
class Child extends Parent {

    public function foo() {
        // process and return data
    }

    public function bar() {
        // process and return data
    }

    // way more methods...

}
```

then is there a generic way in PHP to handle any exceptions thrown in the child methods? For example, a handler in the Parent class? Or do I need to wrap all the methods bodies in a separate try-catch block?

What I want to achieve, is to return an empty `array()` if any of the child methods throw any kind of exception.

Comment: In this situation, I would create a global Event and then listen to it, if any exception in *any* child class has been thrown. simply said, You have to send a signal to the parent class whenever an Exception is "in any child" been thrown.

Comment: True @Vural Acar but what if it's an overridden method.  Is it the same.  Just curious

Comment: @Akintunde, correct and thats why I said *any* child, because you have to inherit to be able to override. so you will have a child class, which throws an exception and you have to fire a signal in that method.

Comment: Awesome @Vural Acar.  All good.  Same principles are being used in frameworks too

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Well, a parent cannot know *all* possible child methods, but it *can* know when an undefined method is called by implementing the `__call` [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

We can use this method to create a try-catch "wrapper" dynamically.

Add this method to your parent:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    // If method call ends with 'Safe'
    $isSafeMethod = substr($method, -strlen('Safe')) === 'Safe';

    if (!$isSafeMethod) {
        trigger_error('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$method.'()', E_USER_ERROR);
        return null;
    }

    // Strip 'Safe' suffix from method name
    $wrappedMethodName = substr($method, 0, strpos($method, 'Safe'));

    try {
        return $this->$wrappedMethodName($args);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Now, anytime you want to invoke this try-catch wrapper, just append "Safe" to the method name that you want to wrap. Full code + example:

```
class TestParent {

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        // If method call ends with 'Safe'
        $isSafeMethod = substr($method, -strlen('Safe')) === 'Safe';

        if (!$isSafeMethod) {
            trigger_error('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$method.'()', E_USER_ERROR);
            return null;
        }

        // Strip 'Safe' suffix from method name
        $wrappedMethodName = substr($method, 0, strpos($method, 'Safe'));

        try {
            return $this->$wrappedMethodName($args);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return [];
        }

    }


}

class TestChild extends TestParent {

    public function throwingMethod()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public function succeedingMethod()
    {
        return 'Success';
    }

}

$child = new TestChild();

// With 'Safe' try-catch invoked in parent
var_dump($child->throwingMethodSafe()); // Empty array
var_dump($child->succeedingMethodSafe()); // 'Success'

// Without 'Safe' try-catch
var_dump($child->throwingMethod()); // throws RuntimeException as expected
```

[Output in 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uXE2O)

Sidenote: Please don't catch the `Exception` class as it is too general and will make debugging a living hell later on ("Why is this method returning an array??")

Answer (score -1):

From my personal experience create customized exception handler and return empty array if you get that exception.
These link will help you to understand the exception handling in PHP:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: OP is talking about an object oriented way.  This is off

Comment: OP knows how to handle exceptions, he is asking, if its possible to catch exceptions in parent class which is thrown in child class.